# Cannot run app in Android Studio. NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to launch a simple app that when you click a button (StartButton), it will launch a Mix() method which will scramble a word chosen randomly from a String array (wordPick) and set the text of a textfield (ScambleF) to it. From there, another button (EnterButton) reads from an editible text field (EnterF) and checks to see if the user inputted word in the EnterF textfield matches the word unscrambled.

Unfortunately I keep getting the following error immediately on launching the app in my emulator. I've searched for an answer here but so far the only thing that has helped is not initializing my variables before onCreate().

EDIT: There is a chronometer added, but right now it has no functionality.

```html
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.roland.scramblegame, PID: 19156

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.roland.scramblegame/com.example.roland.scramblegame.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:87)
at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:81)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getResources(AppCompatActivity.java:541)
at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:409)
at com.example.roland.scramblegame.MainActivity.Fill(MainActivity.java:64)
at com.example.roland.scramblegame.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Here is my Java file

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Random;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String []wordPick;
int track;
Button StartButton, EnterButton;
TextView ScrambleF;
EditText EnterF;
MainActivity run;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    run = new MainActivity();
    wordPick = new String[16];
    wordPick = run.Fill(wordPick);
    StartButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.StartB);
    EnterButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.EnterB);

    StartButton.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Random rand = new Random();
                    track = rand.nextInt(16);
                    ScrambleF = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Question);
                    ScrambleF.setText( run.Mix(wordPick[track]) );
                }
            }
    );

    EnterButton.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    EnterF = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Answer);
                    if (EnterF.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(wordPick[track])) {
                        //Correct
                    }
                    else {
                        //Incorrect
                    }
                }
            }
    );
}


public String[] Fill (String[] array) {
    //Im just going to add random words
    if (array == null) {
        array = wordPick;
    }
    array[0] = getString(R.string.W_Bottle);
    array[1] = getString(R.string.W_Samurai);
    array[2] = getString(R.string.W_Keyboard);
    array[3] = getString(R.string.W_Shrimp);
    array[4] = getString(R.string.W_Project);
    array[5] = getString(R.string.W_Planet);
    array[6] = getString(R.string.W_Walnut);
    array[7] = getString(R.string.W_PacMan);
    array[8] = getString(R.string.W_Shelter);
    array[9] = getString(R.string.W_Android);
    array[10] = getString(R.string.W_Toilet);
    array[11] = getString(R.string.W_Numbers);
    array[12] = getString(R.string.W_Anime);
    array[13] = getString(R.string.W_Goldfish);
    array[14] = getString(R.string.W_Phantom);
    array[15] = getString(R.string.W_Jigsaw);

    return array;
}

public String Mix (String str) {
    //This scrambles up the words in the string array
    if(str == null) {
        str = wordPick[track];
    }
    char[] characters = str.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
        int randomIndex = (int)(Math.random() * characters.length);
        char temp = characters[i];
        characters[i] = characters[randomIndex];
        characters[randomIndex] = temp;
    }

    str = String.valueOf(characters);
    return str;
}
}
```

The manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

And if needed I'll just leave the activity_main.xml here too

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.roland.scramblegame.MainActivity"
android:background="#006699">

<Chronometer
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/chronometer"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="SCRAMBLED WORD"
    android:id="@+id/Question"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="#427030"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/Answer"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="70dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Answer"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:width="250dp"
    android:background="#dddddd"
    android:height="45dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:minHeight="35dp"
    android:inputType="text" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/StartButton"
    android:id="@+id/StartB"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Answer"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Answer"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/EnterButton"
    android:id="@+id/EnterB"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/StartB"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Answer" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You cannot instantiate an `Activity` with `new` and have it work correctly. Why are you trying to do that anyway? Just call your `Fill()` method directly in `onCreate()`. Also, you should follow Java naming conventions, and start your method names with lowercase letters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: "You cannot instantiate an Activity with new and have it work correctly. Why are you trying to do that anyway? Just call your Fill() method directly in onCreate()."

Wow, I got rid of the `new` and it all works now, I'm just a total noob when it comes to coding so I make dumb little mistakes like that. Thanks!!

Comment: It's a surprisingly simple mistake. But just know that the reason you got the crash is because the onCreate (and other methods) are not called when you `new` an Activity, therefore, it's not "hooked up" to anything "behind the scenes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error maybe come from the code below in you `onCreate`:

```
run = new MainActivity();
wordPick = new String[16];
wordPick = run.Fill(wordPick);
```

Are you sure you need to create an activity by `new Activity()`? It's a little strange and not recommended.

try to replace the three lines with :

```
wordPick = Fill(new String[16]);
```

Maybe this can help.

Comment: No... A new Activity is never needed to be created. It is unmanaged by the OS at that point

Answer (score 1):

Just don't initialize a new MainActivity variable. This is not necessary, and it appears to be the cause of your app crash.